# Unable to add SVG with jQuery using the after function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to add a svg to every li with the after function, but they are not appearing.

I tested the svg in the HTML file and it works, so I'm sure there's something wrong on the jQuery code.

The error I'm receiving on the console is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

```js
 $('ul li a').after('<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <path d="M12,12.5857864 L8.70710678,9.29289322 C8.31658249,8.90236893 7.68341751,8.90236893 7.29289322,9.29289322 C6.90236893,9.68341751 6.90236893,10.3165825 7.29289322,10.7071068 L11.2928932,14.7071068 C11.6834175,15.0976311 12.3165825,15.0976311 12.7071068,14.7071068 L16.7071068,10.7071068 C17.0976311,10.3165825 17.0976311,9.68341751 16.7071068,9.29289322 C16.3165825,8.90236893 15.6834175,8.90236893 15.2928932,9.29289322 L12,12.5857864 Z"></path>
                  </svg>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li><a>link1</a> </li>
 <li><a>link2</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have the svg on multiple lines. Try this:

```
 $('ul li a').after(`<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                <path d="M12,12.5857864 L8.70710678,9.29289322 C8.31658249,8.90236893 7.68341751,8.90236893 7.29289322,9.29289322 C6.90236893,9.68341751 6.90236893,10.3165825 7.29289322,10.7071068 L11.2928932,14.7071068 C11.6834175,15.0976311 12.3165825,15.0976311 12.7071068,14.7071068 L16.7071068,10.7071068 C17.0976311,10.3165825 17.0976311,9.68341751 16.7071068,9.29289322 C16.3165825,8.90236893 15.6834175,8.90236893 15.2928932,9.29289322 L12,12.5857864 Z"></path>
              </svg>`);
```

I just replaced the quotes with backticks because they support multi line strings. Another option is to just make the svg a single line string.

Answer (score 1):

You got some syntax error check this code though your image size is too high

```js
$('ul li a').after('<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path d="M12,12.5857864 L8.70710678,9.29289322 C8.31658249,8.90236893 7.68341751,8.90236893 7.29289322,9.29289322 C6.90236893,9.68341751 6.90236893,10.3165825 7.29289322,10.7071068 L11.2928932,14.7071068 C11.6834175,15.0976311 12.3165825,15.0976311 12.7071068,14.7071068 L16.7071068,10.7071068 C17.0976311,10.3165825 17.0976311,9.68341751 16.7071068,9.29289322 C16.3165825,8.90236893 15.6834175,8.90236893 15.2928932,9.29289322 L12,12.5857864 Z"></path></svg>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
<li><a>list 1</a></li>
<li><a>list 2</a></li>
</ul>
```